# GnuPlot terminal LaTeX: \Diamond not centered!

Tags: amsmath, gnuplot

I use the following GnuPlot commands:

```
set terminal latex size 12cm, 7cm
set output "4Kalibratie.tex"
set nokey
set xlabel "kanaal $k$"
set ylabel "$E$ (MeV)"
plot [0:2000] [0:10] 0.00261937*x+4.14561558, "4Kalibratie.txt" using 2:1
```

However where the function is a linear fit, first LaTeX complained about `\Diamond` so I included `\usepackage{amssymb}`, now it can render the PDF, but the diamonds aren't centered on the datapoints: the left corner is positioned exactly there... Either I gave it the wrong package, or I am doing things wrong again!

Answer (score 2):

Specifying point type 2 by

```
plot [0:2000] [0:10] 0.00261937*x+4.14561558, "4Kalibratie.txt" using 2:1 pt 2
```

solved my problem (crosshairs are centered correctly and give more precision).